# Initialize variables from stored procedure results

Tags: sql, variables, initialization

I am still fairly green in SQL, and I have a question.

I am creating a lookup using reporting services that finds an account based on lat/long.  My question is how can I get results from a stored procedure to initialize variables in the following sp?

Example:
--This sp will go out and get the minlat, maxlat, minlong, maxlong based on the zip code.

```
EXEC SERVER.DATABASE.dbo.GetLatLongApprox @Zip
```

--Then I am declaring variables which I will use in the reporting services

```
DECLARE @MaxLat AS float
DECLARE @MinLat AS float
DECLARE @MaxLong AS float
DECLARE @MinLong AS float
```

--Now I want to dynamicaly set the values base on the results of the first stored procedure.

```
SET @MaxLat = ?
SET @MinLat = ?
SET @MaxLong = ?
SET @MinLong = ?
```

This will all reside in one stored procedure that I will use in reporting services. Hopefully this makes sense.  Again, I am green and don't quite have the sql speak down yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

lookup OUTPUT parameters in Books On Line

here is an example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
       @employeeID INT,
       @managerID INT OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
       SELECT @managerID =2

    END
    Go


    declare @employeeID int, @managerID int
    select @employeeID = 1


    exec TestProc @employeeID,@managerID output

    select  @employeeID,@managerID
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use OUTPUT parameters in that.

EXEC SERVER.DATABASE.dbo.GetLatLongApprox @Zip, @MaxLong OUTPUT, ... , @MinLong  OUTPUT

SELECT  @MaxLong as N'@MaxLong'
...
SELECT @MinLong as N'@MinLong'

Is that what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

To do this job you must use output parameters. Like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XPTO_Procedure

@intInput int,
@intOutput int OUTPUT

AS
set @intOutput = @intInput + 1 

go

Call it like this:

declare @intResult int
exec _4P_test 3 ,@intResult OUT
select @intResult
```

It's nice and easy :D

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedure

```
EXEC dbo.GetLatLongApprox @Zip
```

you just need to set the variables against the returned resultset i.e.

```
SELECT
@MinLat = min_lat,
@MaxLat = max_lat,
@MinLong = min_long,
@MaxLong = max_long
FROM
my_resultset

EXEC dbo.MyReportingServiceStoredProcedure @MinLat, @MaxLat, @MinLong, @MaxLong
```

Then pass these as parameters into the reporting services stored procedure, if I have understood you correctly and you are doing this all inside one stored procedure.